# Uploading a CSS id to a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, css

I have some Javascript / Jquery that creates 145 squares. They can be clicked on and it will change the class of the square. The squares also have an id for each one, going from 1 - 145.

This is the script for making the buttons:

```
var number = 1

function makeButton() {
    var button1 = "<div id=\"number\" class=\"inner\" style=\"display:inline-block; margin-top:5px; margin-right: 5px;\"><p>!</p></div>"
    var button2 = button1.replace("number", number)
    $("#buttonz").append(button2);     // Append new elements
    number += 1
};
```

This is the script for creating the squares: 
(The slots variable is 145)

```
function addButtons(){
    for (i = 0; i < slots; i++) {
        makeButton();
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.inner').click(function(){
                            $(this).addClass("selected");
                            $(this).removeClass("inner");
    });
});

    }
}

         $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#clearSlots').click(function(){
                            $('.selected').addClass("inner");
                            $('.selected').removeClass("selected");
                            s = 0;

    });
});
```

I also have a MySQL database that has the columns,

- ID
- isTaken
- pictureLink (already declared variable)

What I want to do is when they click a button (select squares), it should get the id from whatever square(s) they have selected, set isTaken to 1 (corresponding to the id), and then upload pictureLink to the database.

pictureLink will be a link to a picture that will replace the square (same dimensions just a picture) and if someone presses the button (select squares) it will have it set to that picture. The squares with a picture won't be select able, as they are someone else's square. Finally, you should be able to select as many squares as you want and have them all update.

SORRY IF THIS IS CONFUSING, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Move your click handler code out of the loop. It will add a new handler to each existing element for every iteration so the first element will end up with 145 click handlers bound to it.

Also there is no need to wrap the click handler in `document.ready`

Within an event handler, `this` will be the element clicked . You can't repeat ID's in a page but you could get the `index` of the element

```js
function addButtons() {
    for (i = 0; i < slots; i++) {
        makeButton();
    }
    // finish adding elements before adding click handler
    $('.inner').click(function () {
        // `this` is the element event occurred on
        var index = $(this).index();
        $.post('/path/to/server/script/', { taken: index}, function(resp){
            // validate resp and do anything else needed upon success of ajax here
        });

        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).removeClass("inner");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am confused what you are doing with this code:            `$.post('/path/to/server/script/', { taken: index}, function(resp){
            // validate resp and do anything else needed upon success of ajax here
        });`

Comment: using ajax to send the data . really not clear what `pictureLink` means in question

Comment: `pictureLink` is a link to their profile picture, it will be put in place of the square if the square has been selected and clicked the button.

Comment: not enough information in question about that part. How do you know who user is...or what their picture url is?

Comment: I'm using steam api and I already have that setup. There is a variable that is their steam profile picture.